# Loading Multiple Data files from same folder in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load a large number of data files from the same folder in Python. The ultimate goal here is to simply choose which file I would like to use in calculations, rather than individually opening files.

Here is what I have. This seems to work in opening the data in the files, but I am having a hard time choosing a specific file I want to work with (and assigning a value to each column in each file).

```
import astropy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

dir = '/S34_east_tfa/'

import glob, os
os.chdir(dir) 
for file in glob.glob("*.data"):
   data = np.loadtxt(file)
   print (data)
   Time = data[:,0]
```

Comment: The `os.path()` module would probably be useful. What is your condition for choosing files?

Comment: I would like to open every file in the same folder. They are all .data files

Comment: Please provide a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example code. Include what errors you are getting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you mean by "I am having a hard time choosing a specific file I want to work with (and assigning a value to each column in each file)"?

Comment: I want to import all files in the folder, then choose which file from the folder I want to work with later in calculations, rather than loading each file individually. Each file has three columns. I want to use those columns for calculations but not sure how to assign it to a variable for all files not just one file.

Comment: Still not clear on what the precise problem is. If you want to read in a whole load of files you can store the data in an array. For example an array of shape `(N_files, N_cols, N_entries)`. Then you can access whatever data you need based on position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a python dictionary, instead of overwriting the results in `data` variable inside your loop.

```
data_dict = dict()
for file in glob.glob("*.data"):
   data_dict[file] = np.loadtxt(file)
```

Is this what you were looking for?